# GA is not tracking in renewed site

Tags: seo, google-analytics, drupal, tracking

A week ago I renewed my site to simple PHP site to -> DRUPAL 7. I've even transferred the GA script using DRUPAL GA plugin. However, yet GA doesn't track the visitors in my new site.

Could anyone please let me know how can I resolve it.

Here is the URL http://www.icpasrilanka.com/

Comment: hidebyuser.com is not accessible, confirm that you have entered the URL correctly and waited for the DNS to propagate. If the domain has not DNS propagated for more than 48 hours this could be one of the reasons GA is not working.

Comment: I've reinstated the URL, as your saying about DNS issue. Could you please elaborate how can I confirm that and solve it ?

Comment: UA-25244648-1 is this your GA code?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: You got any ideas because yet I couldn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use this plug-in on Chrome - [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en). What it does is check whether all the different Google javascript codes are firing correctly.

Alternatively, plonk the URL your question and I can do a quick check whether your GA is working properly or not :-)

Comment: I've checked with google Tag assistant and say working fine

Comment: Is the Web Property ID that you have fed in the plug-in correct? and are you looking at the correct property dashboard in GA?

Comment: yes, same dashboard

Comment: what does the GA Tracking code status say? is it receiving data or not?

Comment: from the day I've launched the new website no records have recorded. Visitors count everything is 0

Comment: did you try creating a new property and using that code instead?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8039/discussion-between-fazlul-rahman-and-prasad)

Comment: You got any ideas because yet I couldn't solve the issue.